# PassportJS get user by connect.sid

Tags: node.js, express, mean, passport.js

I have a website using PassportJS to handle the authentication.

I'd like to keep user logged in during page refreshing, how can I get the user instance by a given connect.sid stored in the cookie? Is this the best practice by doing this?

Comment: express-session already handles that. What is your problem exactly?